# Clear form post data

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a 3 page system, form > post > submitted, in place. The problem I'm having is that if a user presses the back button from the submitted page, it takes them to the form page, with the values filled in, so if they click submit, it re-inputs the data.

In the usual case, the user goes back to the index page normally, and there's a process by which we check how many times the users ip has appeared in said database (mysql) in the past hour, and limit post ability based on that. But if they press back, that system is void.

The only code I have in place to prevent this is:

```
ob_start();
header('Cache-Control: private');
```

But that seems to do nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: if you use header(Location...) to send them to the index page after processing the form then he post data is cleared.

Comment: The problem there is that I need the 'submitted' page to display information about how they can get back to their individual post.

Comment: And still, if the user just pressed back a few times, they'd be right back in a position to repost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a quick solution for it:

```
<?php
//Check for double post
//Start session
session_start();
$process = true;
if(isset($_POST)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['olddata'])){
       if($_SESSION['olddata'] == $_POST){
          $process = false;
       }
       $_SESSION['olddata'] == $_POST;
    }

}

//Now you can check $process before you do something with the data
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Put the POST check right before the data is submitted or redirect (change header location) to another success/submitted page that contains the information required. That way if they click back they go back to the original submitted page that redirects them back to the success/submitted page.

There are other solutions but it all depends on the purpose- is this to prevent a standard user making a silly mistake or a malicious user.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
```

I can't see how enabling output buffering would prevent this behaviour, so you may wish to omit the ob_start() and ob_flush() calls.

But I do agree it would be better to do:

```
header("Location: mypage.php?somepublicdata=this+is+public");
```

and then use $_SESSION to carry over the $_POST data.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't something like this work? (I haven't tried it out myself.)

```
<head>
<script>
function clearForms()
{
  var i;
  for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
    document.forms[i].reset();
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="clearForms()" onUnload="clearForms()">
</body>
```

Comment: Theoretically yes, the problem is that if the user inputs data wrong, I.e, the bot filter, it asks them to go back and try again, but with this code all of there data would be wiped and they'd have to do it again, which diminishes the user experience...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want now.. Do you have a botfilter? Is it a part of the form? If so, you should probably be able to clear it by using something like this:
document.form_name.input_name.reset();

Not quite sure though.